# Topological Dynamics: closure of forward orbit vs. $\omega$ limit set

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $f: X \rightarrow X$ be continuous, where $X$ is a topological space. This forms a topological dynamical system. For $x \in X$, define $\omega (x) = \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{\cup_{i \geq n}f^{i}(x)}$. Define the forward orbit of $x$ to be $\mathcal{O}^{+}(x) = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f^{n}(x)$. Clearly $\omega (x) \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{O}^{+}(x)}$. My intuition is that $\overline{\mathcal{O}^{+}(x)} - \mathcal{O}^{+}(x) \subseteq \omega (x)$ also holds. Is this true? The closures of two sets that only differ in a finite number of points should be the same, but this reasoning can't be used because we're dealing with an infinite intersection..

**What I've tried:**

Say $z \in \overline{\mathcal{O}^{+}(x)} - \mathcal{O}^{+}(x)$. Then every nbhd $U$ of $z$ contains some $f^{j}(x)$. Fixing $n$, it suffices to show that $z \in \overline{\cup_{i \geq n}f^{i}(x)}$, i.e. that every nbhd $U$ of $z$ also contains some $f^{i}(x)$ for $i \geq n$. Could there be some funky nbhd of $z$ that contains some iterate $f^{k}(x)$ for $k < n$ but never any for $k \geq n$?

For some context, my larger question is: "Is $\overline{\mathcal{O}^{+}(x)}$ f-invariant?" which I think will follow from the answer to the above, since $\omega$-limit sets are $f$-invariant.

Thank you for any help/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is false, as pointed out. The larger question is true however. Indeed, let $y \in \overline{\mathcal{O}^{+}(x)}$ : then there exists integers $n_k$ such that $f^{n_k}(x)$ converges to $y$, by definition. But then $f^{n_k +1}(x)$ converges to $f(y)$ (by continuity of $f$) so $f(y) \in \overline{\mathcal{O}^{+}(x)}$ as well.

It does not imply the first question, because you can perfectly well have two $f$-invariant closed sets $A \subset B$ without having $A=B$ (take $f(x)=x/2$, $A=\{0 \}$, $B=\{1/2^n \} \cup  \{0 \}$).

The property "$B$ is a close $f$-invariant set that does not contain any other $f$-invariant set" is called irreducibility.

Comment: Thanks you! I realized that I worded my question incorrectly the first time around. The correct version is above.

Comment: Do you know of a way prove that $\overline{\mathcal{O}^{+}(x)}$ is $f$-invariant not assuming that the space is first countable(i.e. that we can characterize continuity in terms of limits)? By the way, thank you for the answers and help everyone, they're very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is still not true given your (lack of) hypotheses. You need your space to be at least $T_1$. Heuristically, $\omega(x)$ is the set of points for which the orbit of $x$ under $f$ approaches infinitely often and $\overline{O^{+}(x)}-O^{+}(x)$ is the set of points for which the orbit approaches (but does not meet). Your intuition is right, that the set of points that the $x$ visits often under $f$ should be visited infinitely often, but that relies on the $T_1$ characterization of a limit point $p$ of a set $S$: that every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many members of $S$. Regrettably, in a general topological space, a limit point $p$ of a set $S$ only implies that every neighborhood of $p$ contains a member of $S$.

With that in mind, consider the natural numbers with two zeros. That is, let $\tilde{\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{N}\cup\{*\}$, and let $\{0,*\}$ and the singletons be a basis for your topology. So $0$ and $*$ are topologically indistinguishable.

Define a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ by letting $f(n)=n+1$ if $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(*)=1$. The pre-image of every basic open set is open, and so $f$ is continuous.  With that said, $O^{+}(0)=\mathbb{N}$ and $\overline{O^{+}(0)}\setminus O^{+}(0)=\tilde{\mathbb{N}}\setminus \mathbb{N}=\{*\}$. Moreover, by the same argument in my other answer above/below, $\omega(x)=\emptyset$, the key in this part being the fact that $*$ lies in the closure of the orbit of $0$ but not $f(0)=1$. Since $\{*\}\not\subseteq \emptyset$, this completes the counterexample.

However, since every space you might care about is most likely $T_1$, this is probably not an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; it was very helpful and educational. Yes, X here is a Hausdorff space. I'll try to be more careful with my questions next time.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x+1$. Then $\overline{O^+(x)}=O^+(x)=\{x+n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. For a given $n$, we have $\overline{\cup_{i\ge n}f^i(x)}=\cup_{i\ge n}f^i(x)=\{x+i: i\ge n\}$. So $\cap_{n=1}^m\{x+i: i\ge n\}=\{x+i: i\ge m\}$ and so $\omega(x)=\emptyset$.

So $\omega(x)=\emptyset\subseteq \{x+n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}=\overline{\mathcal{O}^+(X)}$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the reverse inclusion is not true.

Comment: OP changed his question. This answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The closure of $\mathcal O^+(x)$ contains, in particular, all the points in $\mathcal O^+(x)$ itself, and there is no reason that these should be in $\omega(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I worded my question incorrectly - The correct version is above.